# Replacement for obsolete TfsTeamProjectCollection constructors

Tags: tfs, tfs-sdk

I can't find replacement for obsolete `TfsTeamProjectCollection` constructors. This is my current code (it works):

```
UICredentialsProvider uiCredentialsProvider = new UICredentialsProvider();
TfsTeamProjectCollection teamProjectCollection = new TfsTeamProjectCollection(new Uri("tpc uri"), new NetworkCredential("username", "pass", "domain"), uiCredentialsProvider);
```

This code raises tfs login dialog if custom credentials fail. Documentation states that constructors with `TfsClientCredentials` class should be used instead of this one.
How can I use `UICredentialsProvider` with `TfsClientCredentials` class?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the TeamProjectPicker class which provides a dialog to select a collection of TeamFoundation projects.
[Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb141829.aspx)

```
TeamProjectPicker tfsPP = new TeamProjectPicker(TeamProjectPickerMode.MultiProject, false, new UICredentialsProvider());
tfsPP.ShowDialog();
```

Also, you could look at the TfsClientCredentials class with the following constructor. You could then pass this object in.

TfsClientCredentials (
    WindowsCredential windowsCredential,
    bool allowInteractive
)

Comment: I don't need to select team foundation projects. Just want to get user/pass dialog if default credentials doesn't work.